# How to check if a map is a subset of another in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I would like to write a function that checks if a map is a subset of another.

An example of usage should be:

```
(map-subset? {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
=> true
```

Is there a native way to do that?

Comment: What is the definition of this subset relation you speak off?  Subset on keys, and the same values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making an assumption on what you mean by subset (direct translation of that definition):

```
(and (every? (set (keys m1)) (keys m2))  ;; subset on keys
     (every? #(= (m1 %)(m2 %)) (keys m2)))   ;; on that subset all the same values
```

Answer (score 26):

By converting the maps to sets, you can use `clojure.set/subset?`

```
(clojure.set/subset? (set {:a 1 :b 2}) (set {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))
=> true
```

This would make each pair of the map an element in the set

```
 (set {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
 => #{[:b 2] [:c 3] [:a 1]}
```

And as such, `{:a 1 :b 3}` would not be a subset

```
(clojure.set/subset? (set {:a 1 :b 3}) (set {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))
=> false
```

Answer (score 13):

```
(defn submap?
  "Checks whether m contains all entries in sub."
  [^java.util.Map m ^java.util.Map sub]
  (.containsAll (.entrySet m) (.entrySet sub)))
```

REPL demo:

```
(submap? {:foo 1 :bar 2 :quux 3} {:foo 1 :bar 2})
;= true
(submap? {:foo 1 :bar 2 :quux 3} {:foo 1 :bar 3})
;= false
(submap? {:foo 1 :bar 2} {:foo 1 :bar 2 :quux 3})
;= false
```

Comment: Are type hints preferred in this case? If yes, would you please tell why?

Comment: @Chiron Because without them, all three method calls would be reflective and the function would be terribly slow. With type hints added, I'd expect this to be among the fastest possible solutions.

Answer (score 7):

Another option could be:

```
(defn submap? [a b]
  (= a (select-keys b (keys a))))
```

This will only check equity of the keys in the first map.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you intend the keys and the values to match ...

> Is there a native way to do that?

There is no standard function. I suggest ...

```
(defn map-subset? [a-map b-map]
  (every? (fn [[k _ :as entry]] (= entry (find b-map k))) a-map))
```

A few examples:

```
(map-subset? {:a 1 :b 2} {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
=> true

(map-subset? {:d 4} {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
=> false

(map-subset? {:a 3} {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
=> false

(map-subset? {:a nil} {})
=> false
```

- It traverses its first argument just once.
- It handles `nil` values properly.

If neither of these are important, go with a more elegant version such as [kasterma's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20421990/1562315).

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible ways to solve your question. One quick possible solution would be:

```
(defn contains-submap? [map-structure keys] 
  (every? (partial contains? map-structure) keys)) 

(contains-submap? {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} (keys {:a 1 :b 2}))
true
```

It can be done with Sets for example.  But as @kasterma pointed, it depends on your original intend.